# Why is my article not embedding properly into Facebook post?

Tags: html, facebook

When I embed an article from one of my websites as a Facebook post by pasting the url of the article into the post, it sometimes pulls in text and images that are not related to the main article (sidebar etc).

My main article is contained within an article tag in a page properly marked up as html5. Is there some special markup that I should be aware off?

Comment: Debug the url at https://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug/og/object/

Comment: Interesting. Thanks a lot. Provide it as an answer and I'll accept it as the 'Warnings That Should Be Fixed' part is what I was asking for.